# Mongo DB in c#: Transaction not working - what I'm doing wrong?

Tags: c#, mongodb, transactions

I have a situation like this:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient("connection-bla-bla");
var mongoDB = mongoClient.GetDatabase("db-name");
using (var session = mongoDB.Client.StartSession())
{
    session.StartTransaction();
    var collection = mongoDB.GetCollection<Rec>("collectionName");
    collection.InsertOne(new Rec() { Name = "Record1" });
    collection.InsertOne(new Rec() { Name = "Record2" });
    session.CommitTransaction();
}
```

This code works quite fine, Record1 and Record2 are written.

However, when i try this ...

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient("connection-bla-bla");
var mongoDB = mongoClient.GetDatabase("db-name");
using (var session = mongoDB.Client.StartSession())
{
    session.StartTransaction();
    var collection = mongoDB.GetCollection<Rec>("collectionName");
    collection.InsertOne(new Rec() { Name = "Record1" });
    if (DateTime.UtcNow > DateTime.MinValue) throw new Exception("Bad things happens");
    collection.InsertOne(new Rec() { Name = "Record2" });
    session.CommitTransaction();
}
```

... Record1 is written, even the transaction is not comitted. I guess I miss here something, but  have no clue what.
Thanks for code correction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use the transaction, you need to specify the session when calling the insert commands:

```
var mongoClient = new MongoClient("connection-bla-bla");
var mongoDB = mongoClient.GetDatabase("db-name");
using (var session = mongoDB.Client.StartSession())
{
    session.StartTransaction();
    var collection = mongoDB.GetCollection<Rec>("collectionName");
    collection.InsertOne(session, new Rec() { Name = "Record1" });
    if (DateTime.UtcNow > DateTime.MinValue) throw new Exception("Bad things happens");
    collection.InsertOne(session, new Rec() { Name = "Record2" });
    session.CommitTransaction();
}
```

There are overloads for various write commands that accept the session. See this [link](https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.16/reference/driver/crud/sessions_and_transactions/) for details.

Comment: Thanks Markus! I was thinking of it as an ambient scope: wrong ... :D